# If I am refused a Canadian study visa, will it affect my study visa application for Germany?

Tags: study

I have an Australian degree from their off-shore campus in Malaysia. I have been a frequent traveler during my bachelors. I recently applied for a Post Graduate Diploma in Canada and unfortunately it got refused.
The reason of refusal being: "I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your stay".

Now I have got an admission in TU Dresden, one of the top universities in Germany. Now the problem is, I am not sure if my German Visa application will be affected by the refusal. How can I avoid a rejection in this case.

Comment: Are you a Malaysian citizen?

Comment: No, Pakistani. I studied at Curtin Malaysia.

Answer (score 2):

Refusal from Canada in itself does not affect your application. The [application form](https://videx-national.diplo.de/videx/visum-erfassung/#/videx-langfristiger-aufenthalt) for Germany does not ask you about past refusals from other countries.

However, whatever caused your application for Canada to be refused may also cause your German application to be refused.

Unlike UK, Canadian visa officers do not always provide more detailed information on the reasons of refusal. But if any information is provided, you should review that part of  your application.

Usually, the refusal letter should say the general reason the officer based his refusal on, e.g. "I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your stay, as stipulated in subsection 216(1) of the IRPR, based on the purpose of your visit/financial situation/insufficient family ties/etc."

Comment: Its about "purpose of visit".

Comment: The German Embassy in Pakistan requires us to submit the refusal document and explain the reason of refusal.

Comment: @HassanRiaz Unfortunately purpose of visit is the vaguest answer the officer can give. Perhaps the procedure is different in Pakistan, but in other countries, Germany does not ask for other countries' refusals. (Where did they ask you if you have had any refusals from other countries?)